# Fatal error: Call to a member function getProductLink() on a non-object

Tags: php, prestashop, google-shopping

I just bought a module for the prestashop the guy told me that it was ok for PS 1.5 but in fact it was not.

I had a lot of mistakes and with some help I removed them step by step.

Actually I have a last one:

It told me
 `Fatal error: Call to a member function getProductLink() on a non-object in /htdocs/modules/googleshopping/googleshopping.php on line 420`

Here is the entire function

```
 <?php
    /*
     *
     * Google Shopping
     * Licence d'utilisation requise (voir readme.txt)
     *
     *
     */

    require_once(_PS_MODULE_DIR_.'googleshopping'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'class'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'myTools.php');
    require_once(_PS_MODULE_DIR_.'googleshopping'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'class'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'html2text.inc.php');
    require_once(_PS_MODULE_DIR_.'googleshopping'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'fonctions.php');             // fonctions

    class GoogleShopping extends Module
    {
        function __construct()
        {
            $this->name = 'googleshopping';
            $this->tab = 'Igwane.com';
            $this->version = '2.0';

            parent::__construct();

            $config = Configuration::getMultiple(array('IGW_DOMAIN', 'IGW_LICNUM'));
            if (isset($config['IGW_DOMAIN']))
                $this->_domain = $config['IGW_DOMAIN'];
            if (isset($config['IGW_LICNUM']))
                $this->_licnum = $config['IGW_LICNUM'];


            if ($this->_domain!=$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']):
                $this->warning = $this->l('L\'utilisation de ce module n\'est pas autorisée sur ce domaine');
            else:
                try {
                    $handle = fopen("http://www.igwane.com/check_licence.php?domain=".$this->_domain.'&licence='.$this->_licnum, "rb");
                    $valid_licence = '';
                    while (!feof($handle)) {
                      $valid_licence .= fread($handle, 8192);
                    }
                    fclose($handle);
                    if ($valid_licence!='OK'):
                       $this->_licnum=null;
                    endif;

                    if (empty($this->_domain) OR empty($this->_licnum))
                        $this->warning = $this->l('L\'utilisation de ce module n\'est pas autorisée sur ce domaine sans licence (gratuite) - www.igwane.com');

                    $handle = fopen("http://www.igwane.com/googleshopping_current_version.txt", "rb");
                    $current_version = '';
                    while (!feof($handle)) {
                      $current_version .= fread($handle, 8192);
                    }
                    fclose($handle);
                    if ($current_version!=$this->version)
                      $this->warning = $this->l('Une nouvelle version (v'.$current_version.') est disponible.');

                } catch (Exception $e) {

                }
            endif;
            $this->page = basename(__FILE__, '.php');
            $this->displayName = $this->l('Google Shopping by Igwane.com');
            $this->description = $this->l('Exportez vos produits vers Google Shopping.');
        }

        function install()
        {
            if(!parent::install())
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }


        public function getContent()
        {
            if(isset($_POST['generate']))
            {
                if(isset($_POST['shipping']))
                {
                    Configuration::updateValue('GS_SHIPPING', $_POST['shipping']);

                }

            if(isset($_POST['image']))
            {
                Configuration::updateValue('GS_IMAGE', $_POST['image']);
            }

            // Récupération des langues actives pour la boutique
            $languages = Language::getLanguages();
            foreach ($languages as $i => $lang)
            {
                if(isset($_POST['product_type_'.$lang['iso_code']]))
                {
                    Configuration::updateValue('GS_PRODUCT_TYPE_'.$lang['iso_code'], $_POST['product_type_'.$lang['iso_code']]);
                }
            }

            if(isset($_POST['DOMAIN']))
            {
                Configuration::updateValue('IGW_DOMAIN', rtrim($_POST['DOMAIN']));
            }

            if(isset($_POST['LICNUM']))
            {
                Configuration::updateValue('IGW_LICNUM', $_POST['LICNUM']);
            }


                // Endroit où générer les fichiers
                if(isset($_POST['generate_root']) && $_POST['generate_root'] === "on")
                {
                    Configuration::updateValue('GENERATE_FILE_IN_ROOT', intval(1));

                } else {
                    Configuration::updateValue('GENERATE_FILE_IN_ROOT', intval(0));
                    @mkdir($path_parts["dirname"].'/file_exports', 0755, true);
                    @chmod($path_parts["dirname"].'/file_exports', 0755);
                }
                // Gtin - Code EAN13
                if(isset($_POST['gtin']) && $_POST['gtin'] === "on")
                {
                    Configuration::updateValue('GTIN', intval(1));
                } else {
                    Configuration::updateValue('GTIN', intval(0));
                }
                // Référence fabricant
                if(isset($_POST['mpn']) && $_POST['mpn'] === "on")
                {
                    Configuration::updateValue('MPN', intval(1));
                } else {
                    Configuration::updateValue('MPN', intval(0));
                }
                // Quantité
                if(isset($_POST['quantity']) && $_POST['quantity'] === "on")
                {
                    Configuration::updateValue('QUANTITY', intval(1));
                } else {
                    Configuration::updateValue('QUANTITY', intval(0));
                }
                // Marque
                if(isset($_POST['brand']) && $_POST['brand'] === "on")
                {
                    Configuration::updateValue('BRAND', intval(1));
                } else {
                    Configuration::updateValue('BRAND', intval(0));
                }
                // Description
                if(isset($_POST['description']) && $_POST['description'] != 0)
                {
                    Configuration::updateValue('DESCRIPTION', intval($_POST['description']));
                }

                //Offre spéciale
                if(isset($_POST['featured_product']) && $_POST['featured_product'] === "on")
                {
                    Configuration::updateValue('FEATURED_PRODUCT', intval(1));
                } else {
                    Configuration::updateValue('FEATURED_PRODUCT', intval(0));
                }
                self::generateFileList();
            }

            $output = '<h2>'.$this->displayName.'</h2>';
            $output .= $this->_displayForm();

            // Bloc liens vers les fichiers générés
            $output .= '<fieldset class="space width3">
                            <legend>'.$this->l('Fichiers').'</legend>
                            <p><b>'.$this->l('Liens des fichiers générés').'</b></p>';

            // Récupération des langues actives pour la boutique
            $languages = Language::getLanguages();
            foreach ($languages as $i => $lang)
            {
                if(Configuration::get('GENERATE_FILE_IN_ROOT') == 1)
                {
                    $get_file_url = 'http://'.myTools::getHttpHost(false, true).__PS_BASE_URI__.'googleshopping-'.$lang['iso_code'].'.xml';
                } else {
                    $get_file_url = 'http://'.myTools::getHttpHost(false, true).__PS_BASE_URI__.'modules/'.$this->getName().'/file_exports/googleshopping-'.$lang['iso_code'].'.xml';
                }

                $output .='<a href="'.$get_file_url.'">'.$get_file_url.'</a><br />';
            }

            $output .='<hr><p><b>Génération automatique des fichiers</b></p>
            '.$this->l('Vous devez installer une règle CRON qui appellera le fichier suivant chaque jour ').'<br/>http://'.myTools::getHttpHost(false, true).__PS_BASE_URI__.'modules/'.$this->getName().'/cron.php'.'</p>
            </fieldset>';


            return $output;
        }

        private function _displayForm()
        {

            $options = '';
            $mpn = '';
            $generate_file_in_root = '';
            $quantity = '';
            $brand = '';
            $gtin = '';
            $selected_short = '';
            $selected_long = '';
            $featured_product = '';

            // Checked sur la generate_root box si on veut générer les fichiers à la racine du site
            if(Configuration::get('GENERATE_FILE_IN_ROOT') == 1)
            {
                $generate_file_in_root = "checked";
            }

            // Balises googleshopping optionnelles
            if(Configuration::get('GTIN') == 1)
            {
                $gtin = "checked";
            }
            if(Configuration::get('MPN') == 1)
            {
                $mpn = "checked";
            }
            if(Configuration::get('QUANTITY') == 1)
            {
                $quantity = "checked";
            }
            if(Configuration::get('BRAND') == 1)
            {
                $brand = "checked";
            }
            if(Configuration::get('FEATURED_PRODUCT') == 1)
            {
                $featured_product = "checked";
            }

            (intval(Configuration::get('DESCRIPTION')) === intval(1)) ? $selected_short = "selected" : $selected_long = "selected";

            $form = '
            <form action="'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'" method="post">


            <fieldset style="float: right; width: 255px">
                        <legend>'.$this->l('A propos').'</legend>
                        <p style="font-size: 1.5em; font-weight: bold; padding-bottom: 0">'.$this->displayName.' '.$this->version.'</p>
                        <p style="clear: both">
                        '.$this->description.'
                        </p>
                        <p><center><a href="http://www.igwane.com" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.igwane.com/images/logo.jpg"><img src="http://www.igwane.com/images/devis-gratuit.gif"></a></center></p>
                        <p><center><a href="/modules/googleshopping/readme.txt">'.$this->l('Lire les dernières mises à jour (readme.txt)').'</a></p>
                        <p>'.($this->_licnum?'':'<a style="color: #7ba45b; text-decoration: underline;" href="http://www.igwane.com/fr/contact" target="_blank">Demandez votre licence d\'utilisation gratuite (précisez votre nom de domaine)</a>').'</p>
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset class="space width3">
            <legend>'.$this->l('Paramètres').'</legend>';

            if (!$this->_licnum):
            $form.='
                <label>'.$this->l('Licence accordée à').' </label>
                <div class="margin-form">
                    <input type="text" name="DOMAIN" value="'.Configuration::get('IGW_DOMAIN').'" size="40">
                </div>
                <label>'.$this->l('Numéro de licence').' </label>
                <div class="margin-form">
                    <input type="text" name="LICNUM" value="'.Configuration::get('IGW_LICNUM').'" size="40">
                </div>
            ';
            else:
               $form.='
                <label>'.$this->l('Licence accordée à').' </label>
                <div class="margin-form">
                    <input type="text" name="DOMAIN" readonly value="'.Configuration::get('IGW_DOMAIN').' "size="40">
                </div>

            ';
            endif;

            $form.='
                <label>'.$this->l('Type de description').' </label>
                <div class="margin-form">
                    <select name="description">
                        <option value="1" '.$selected_short.'>'.$this->l('Description courte').'</option>
                        <option value="2" '.$selected_long.'>'.$this->l('Description longue').'</option>
                    </select>
                </div>';

            // Récupération des langues actives pour la boutique
            $languages = Language::getLanguages();
            foreach ($languages as $i => $lang)
            {
                $form.='<label title="product_type_'.$lang['iso_code'].'">'.$this->l('Catégorie Google').' '.strtoupper($lang['iso_code']).'</label>
                <div class="margin-form">
                    <input type="text" name="product_type_'.$lang['iso_code'].'" value="'.Configuration::get('GS_PRODUCT_TYPE_'.$lang['iso_code']).'" size="40">
                    <br />(<a href="http://www.google.com/support/merchants/bin/answer.py?answer=160081&query=product_type" target="_blank">'.$this->l('Voir Catégorie Google').'</a>)
                </div>';
            }


            $form.='<label title="[shipping]">'.$this->l('Frais de port').' </label>
                <div class="margin-form">
                    <input type="text" name="shipping" value="'.Configuration::get('GS_SHIPPING').'">
                </div>

                <label title="[image]">'.$this->l('Type de l\'image').' </label>
                <div class="margin-form">
                    <input type="text" name="image" value="'.((Configuration::get('GS_IMAGE')!='')?(Configuration::get('GS_IMAGE')):'large').'">
                </div>

                <hr>

                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label>'.$this->l('Générer les fichiers à la racine du site').'</label></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="generate_root" '.$generate_file_in_root.'></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label>'.$this->l('Références fabricants').'</label></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="mpn" '.$mpn.' title="'.$this->l('Recommandé par Google').'"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label>'.$this->l('Quantité de produits').'</label></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="quantity" '.$quantity.' title="'.$this->l('Recommandé par Google').'"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label title="[brand]">'.$this->l('Marque').'</label></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="brand" '.$brand.' title="'.$this->l('Recommandé par Google').'"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label>'.$this->l('Code EAN13').'</label></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="gtin" '.$gtin.' title="'.$this->l('Recommandé par Google').'"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label>'.$this->l('En solde').'</label></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="featured_product" '.$featured_product.'></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <br>
                <center><input name="generate" type="submit" value="'.$this->l('Générer les fichiers').'"></center>
            </fieldset>
            </form>
            ';
            return $form;
        }

        public function getName()
        {
            $output = $this->name;
            return $output;
        }

        public function uninstall()
        {
            Configuration::deleteByName('GS_PRODUCT_TYPE');
            Configuration::deleteByName('GS_SHIPPING');

            Configuration::deleteByName('IGW_DOMAIN');
            Configuration::deleteByName('IGW_LICNUM');

            return parent::uninstall();
        }

        public static function generateFileList()
        {
            // Récupération des langues actives pour la boutique
            $languages = Language::getLanguages();
            foreach ($languages as $i => $lang)
            {
                self::generateFile($lang);
            }
        }

        private static function generateFile($lang)
        {
            global $link;
            $path_parts = pathinfo(__FILE__);

            if (Configuration::get('GENERATE_FILE_IN_ROOT')):
                $generate_file_path = '../googleshopping-'.$lang['iso_code'].'.xml';
                else:
                $generate_file_path = $path_parts["dirname"].'/file_exports/googleshopping-'.$lang['iso_code'].'.xml';
                endif;

            //Google Shopping XML
            $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>'."\n";
            $xml .= '<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0" encoding="UTF-8" >'."\n";
            $xml .= '<title>'.Configuration::get('PS_SHOP_NAME').'</title>'."\n";
            $xml .= '<link href="http://'.myTools::getHttpHost(false, true).__PS_BASE_URI__.'" rel="alternate" type="text/html"/>'."\n";
            $xml .= '<modified>'.date('Y-m-d').'T01:01:01Z</modified><author><name>'.Configuration::get('PS_SHOP_NAME').'</name></author>'."\n";

            $googleshoppingfile = fopen($generate_file_path,'w');

            fwrite($googleshoppingfile, $xml);

            $sql='SELECT * FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'product p'.
            ' LEFT JOIN '._DB_PREFIX_.'product_lang pl ON p.id_product = pl.id_product'.
            ' WHERE p.active = 1 AND pl.id_lang='.$lang['id_lang'];

            $products = Db::getInstance()->ExecuteS($sql);

            $site_base = __PS_BASE_URI__;       // préfix du site
            $url_site = myTools::getHttpHost(false, true);  // url du site base Serveur
            $url_site_base_prestashop = $url_site.$site_base;

            $title_limit = 70;
            $description_limit = 10000;

            $languages = Language::getLanguages();
            $tailleTabLang = sizeof($languages);

            foreach($products as $product)
            {
                $xml_googleshopping ='';
                $cat_link_rew = Category::getLinkRewrite($product['id_category_default'], intval($lang));
                $product['details'] = new Product((int)($product['id_product']), false, $lang['id_lang']);
                $product_link = $link->getProductLink((int)($product['details']->id), $product['details']->link_rewrite, $cat_link_rew, $product['details']->ean13, $lang['id_lang']);

                $title_crop = $product['name'];
                if(strlen($product['name']) > $title_limit)
                {
                    $title_crop = substr($title_crop, 0, ($title_limit-1));
                    $title_crop = substr($title_crop, 0, strrpos($title_crop," "));
                }

                if(intval(Configuration::get('DESCRIPTION')) === intval(2))
                {
                    $description_crop = $product['description'];
                } else {
                    $description_crop = $product['description_short'];
                }
                $description_crop = myTools::f_convert_text("", $description_crop, false);

                if(strlen($description_crop) > $description_limit)
                {
                    $description_crop = substr($description_crop, 0, ($description_limit-1));
                    $description_crop = substr($description_crop, 0, strrpos($description_crop," "));
                }
                $xml_googleshopping .= '<entry>'."\n";
                $xml_googleshopping .= '<g:id>'.$product['id_product'].'-'.$lang['iso_code'].'</g:id>'."\n";
                $xml_googleshopping .= '<title>'.htmlspecialchars(ucfirst(mb_strtolower($title_crop,'UTF-8'))).'</title>'."\n";
                $xml_googleshopping .= '<link>'.$product_link.'</link>'."\n";
                $xml_googleshopping .= '<g:price>'.Product::getPriceStatic($product['id_product'],true,NULL,2).'</g:price>'."\n";
                $xml_googleshopping .= '<g:description>'.htmlspecialchars($description_crop, null, 'UTF-8', false).'</g:description>'."\n";
                $xml_googleshopping .= '<g:condition>new</g:condition>'."\n"; //condition = neuf, occasion, reconditionné OR new, used, refurbished

                if(Configuration::get('MPN') && $product['supplier_reference'] != '')
                {
                    $xml_googleshopping .= '<g:mpn>'.$product['supplier_reference'].'</g:mpn>'; //ref fabricant
                }

                // Pour chaque image
                $images = Image::getImages($lang['id_lang'], $product['id_product']);
                $indexTabLang = 0;

                if($tailleTabLang >1 ){         
                    while(sizeof($images) < 1 && $indexTabLang<$tailleTabLang){
                        if($languages[$indexTabLang]['id_lang']!=$lang['id_lang']){
                            $images = Image::getImages($languages[$indexTabLang]['id_lang'], $product['id_product']);
                        }
                         $indexTabLang++;   
                    }
                }

                $nbimages=0;
                $image_type=Configuration::get('GS_IMAGE');
                    if ($image_type=='') $image_type='large';

                foreach($images as $im)
                {
                  // Old URL
                  //$image='http://'.$url_site_base_prestashop.'img/p/'.$product['id_product'].'-'.$im['id_image'].'-large.jpg';
                  $image= $link->getImageLink($product['link_rewrite'], $product['id_product'] .'-'. $im['id_image'],$image_type);
                  // BUG :
                  //if (!strpos($url_site_base_prestashop,$image))
                  //  $image = 'http://'.$url_site_base_prestashop.$image;
                  $xml_googleshopping .= '<g:image_link>'.$image.'</g:image_link>'."\n";
                  if (++$nbimages == 10) break;
                }

                // Quantité et disponibilité
                if(Configuration::get('QUANTITY') == 1)
                {
                    if ($product['quantity'] != '' && $product['quantity'] != '0')
                        {
                            $xml_googleshopping .= '<g:quantity>'.$product['quantity'].'</g:quantity>'."\n";
                            $xml_googleshopping .= '<g:availability>in stock</g:availability>'."\n";
                        }
                        else{
                            $xml_googleshopping .= '<g:quantity>0</g:quantity>'."\n";
                            $xml_googleshopping .= '<g:availability>out of stock</g:availability>'."\n";
                        }
                }

                // Marque
                if(Configuration::get('BRAND') && $product['id_manufacturer'] != '0')
                {
                    $xml_googleshopping .= '<g:brand>'.htmlspecialchars(Manufacturer::getNameById(intval($product['id_manufacturer'])), null, 'UTF-8', false).'</g:brand>'."\n";
                }

                // Catégorie
                if(Configuration::get('GS_PRODUCT_TYPE_'.$lang['iso_code']))
                {
                    $product_type = str_replace('>', '&gt;', Configuration::get('GS_PRODUCT_TYPE_'.$lang['iso_code']));
                    $product_type = str_replace('&', '&amp;', $product_type);
                    $xml_googleshopping .= '<g:google_product_category>'.$product_type.'</g:google_product_category>'."\n";
                    $xml_googleshopping .= '<g:product_type>'.$product_type.'</g:product_type>'."\n";               
                }

                // Frais de port
                if(Configuration::get('GS_SHIPPING'))
                {
                    $xml_googleshopping .= '<g:shipping>'."\n";
                    $xml_googleshopping .= '<g:country>FR</g:country>'."\n";
                    $xml_googleshopping .= '<g:service>Standard</g:service>'."\n";
                    $xml_googleshopping .= '<g:price>'.Configuration::get('GS_SHIPPING').'</g:price>'."\n";
                    $xml_googleshopping .= '</g:shipping>'."\n";
                }

                //Poids
                if($product['weight'] != '0')
                {
                    $xml_googleshopping .= '<g:shipping_weight>'.$product['weight'].' kilograms</g:shipping_weight>'."\n";
                }

                // Offre spéciale


        if(Configuration::get('FEATURED_PRODUCT') == 1 && $product['on_sale'] != '0')
            {
                $xml_googleshopping .= '<g:featured_product>o</g:featured_product>'."\n";
            }


            if(Configuration::get('GTIN') && $product['ean13'] != '')
            {
                $xml_googleshopping .= '<g:gtin>'.$product['ean13'].'</g:gtin>'."\n";

            }
                $xml_googleshopping .= '</entry>'."\n";

            // Ecriture du produit dans l'XML googleshopping
            fwrite($googleshoppingfile, $xml_googleshopping);
        }

        $xml = '</feed>';
        fwrite($googleshoppingfile, $xml);
        fclose($googleshoppingfile);

        @chmod($generate_file_path, 0777);
        return true;
    }
}
?>
```

the line concerned is this one on the line 420 :

```
 $product_link = $link->getProductLink((int)($product['details']->id), $product['details']->link_rewrite, $cat_link_rew, $product['details']->ean13, $lang['id_lang']);
```

I really do not know where doesd it come from but I have this fatal error 
`Fatal error: Call to a member function getProductLink() on a non-object in /htdocs/modules/googleshopping/googleshopping.php on line 420`

anykind of help will be much appreciated.

Comment: whats the type of your $link object? which class' object is it?

Comment: how can I know that informations ?

Comment: lol that was foolish of me, i can check in your code! let me see

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I'm really a new in that domain. In fact I bought the module for prestashop and the guy who was supposed to do support do not answer

Comment: Try replacing $link-> with $this-> in that line

Comment: cant realy see where $link is coming from in that long code

Comment: now it dispaly this Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in /htdocs/modules/googleshopping/googleshopping.php on line 420

Comment: Probably answer by @konsolenfreddy is  correct. Look for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `generateFile` uses the global `$link` variable.

You have probably forgotten to include an additional file (which instantiates the object  in the `$link` variable).

Comment: how do I include that file ?

Comment: I don't know prestashop to well, but from what it looks like there might be a dependency to some plugin for link generation: http://addons.prestashop.com/en/search?search_query=link I'd suggest you try getting support from where you bought it, it seems to be a to localized issue.

Comment: ok, I will call once again the support. Thank you so much for the help

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
$link->getProductLink
```

to:

```
Context::getContext()->link->getProductLink
```

You will have another error in this same file with `var getImageLink`

Do the same thing. Change:

```
$link->getImageLink
```

to:

```
Context::getContext()->link->getImageLink
```

Answer (score 1):

The script expects a variable named `$link` which is supposedly not set. Since it's `global`, it can be [defined outside the function](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Look for the file that defines `$link` and include it correctly